# Overloaded Constructors c#

Tags: c#, constructor, constructor-overloading

I have 1 namespace(DXApplication5) and 2 classes inside. I am trying to refresh the gridview with a class. What am I doing wrong with the piece of code below? Thx in advance,

> Errors:The best overloaded method match for
>   'DXApplication5.grid_refresh.grid_refresh(DXApplication5.Form1)' has
>   some invalid arguments
>
> Argument 1: cannot convert from 'DevExpress.XtraEditors.XtraForm' to
>   'DXApplication5.Form1'

```
public class grid_refresh
{
    public DXApplication5.Form1 frm1;

    public grid_refresh()
    {
        //Default Constructor   
    }

    public grid_refresh(DXApplication5.Form1 frm1)
    {
       frm1.gcStudent.Refresh();
    }        
}
```

//Calling from another class

```
 DXApplication5.grid_refresh gr = new grid_refresh(frm1);
```

Comment: How is frm1 that's being passed to grid_refresh being instantiated? You only show us A declaration for an object frm1 but you don't actually show us the instantiation.

Comment: try to pass entities of first form to other then use the enitites to fill or refresh grid  form not passes directly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the `frm1` you are passing is an instance of `DevExpress.XtraEditors.XtraForm`, not `DXApplication5.Form1`.

Solution 1: Write a constructor which accepts a `DevExpress.XtraEditors.XtraForm` as a parameter.

```
 public grid_refresh(DevExpress.XtraEditors.XtraForm frm1)
 {
       ...
 }
```

Solution 2: Make `frm1` to be an instance of `DXApplication5.Form1`.